Should we provide guidance warning not to trust ChatGPT?
These days one often finds questions that include stuff along the lines of, “and ChatGPT tells me blah-blah,” where blah-blah is some utter garbage. Correcting the misapprehensions that stem from ill-advised reliance on such AI systems has come to feel like trying to bail out a swimming pool with a thimble.
I propose that we provide—somewhere in the help center?—a warning about the substantial limitations of those… those… (I hesitate to call them resources). The kind of information that I think it’s very important for users of ELL to understand is presented beautifully by this short essay at Scientific American.
I do get that the purpose of ELL is to answer questions, and that our help center focuses on matters like “What issues are on topic here?” and “How should I craft my question for maximum value?”  We are mostly about how to use English rather than how to avoid being misled in learning how to use English. So the kind of guidance I propose would have a different feel to most of the existing guidance.
The advice I propose would of course be directly on topic at our Language Learning sister site. But it’s certainly not clear that very many who post here have first studied up over there. Nor should we set any expectation that they do so.
At the least, I think it would be good if we here at ELL had a standard, well-crafted statement (aimed particularly to the needs of learners of English) to which we could point (by, say, including a link) within our answers to those questions that reflect over-reliance on these AI bots. If there’s interest, I’d be happy to draft something up.

You could add a wiki answer to Contributor's Guide to ELL. It was intended to be a community created and maintained resource for all sorts of guidance that members can be directed to for more information.

Adding something to the help centre should only happen when we're responding to an actual chronic problem, not something we think might be happening or might happen down the road.
Right now, I don't see questions including AI output causing any problems --AI-based answers yes, but questions no-- so I don't see the need to educate users about them.
Further, while helping people learn is the goal of this site, we teach the English language here. Educating users about tools from outside the SE network feels like mission creep.

Premise
I'm widening the scope of my answer to respond to a couple of ELL users who deride, and belittle questions that are inspired by an AI bot's answer.

The fear that users are relying excessively on AI and posting questions based on its generated "garbage" is, in my opinion, overstated. AI-inspired questions are no different from someone asking, “My teacher said you always use the present tense after ‘when’. Is that true?”
It is undeniable that millions of people have been using LLMs to varying degrees of success, if the majority of solutions generated by ChatGPT, Gemini, Copilot etc.  were inaccurate, incorrect or just plain garbage this cultural phenomenon would have died two years ago. It's also true that a couple of users on EL&U and ELL have a knee-jerk reaction whenever someone admits to using AI, the resulting downvotes, and successful attempts to close the question result in two things. First, frightening (or annoying) the new contributor to such a degree they refrain from ever posting a second question. Secondly, the more confident learner learns not to mention the name of the LLM in any future post.  Also, how would the community ascertain whether a user consulted ChatGPT or Gemini before posting their question if the asker never mentions their research, as so many are wont to do?
The OP of this feature wants to dissuade or warn learners from trusting LLMs as a resource. If the OP explained and provided real-life examples of those pitfalls that would be useful for future visitors but I would really hope the piece is objective and avoids using emotional language such as "garbage", "bullshitting", and "bullshit machines" (from the linked essay).
The following conclusion from the Scientific American essay, is a valid one, and worth reminding younger users.

We worry that talking of AI “hallucinating”—a term usually used for human psychology—risks anthropomorphizing the chatbots.

The same criticism can be said if we replace "hallucinating" with "bullshitting",  I disagree that the expletive  avoids the risk of humanising AI bots. Only people can bullshit; not things, not animals and not a computer programme however advanced. Everyone agrees that LLMs are insentient, unable to be original, "think" or "understand" problems but they are very capable of reproducing human-like text.
Going back to ELL, how many visitors, especially non-native speakers, actually spend any time on the help centre page? How many have sufficient control of English to understand everything written in What questions should I avoid asking and How do I ask a good question?. It is human nature to look for shortcuts and quick solutions to difficult problems, and a Q&A website is no different. This impatience and lack of effort can be attributed to the Internet. And as younger users visit the site and ask questions, the lack of research and effort is destined to increase.
I am not the best person to answer whether the OP's proposal is a worthy one, there are users more qualified and more eloquent than I,  but in the hope this answer stirs a response, we need to hold a discussion on this critical issue.

If this warning was similar to the warning we provide about when to trust a grammar checker, it would be fine. I agree with you that the linked essay is not an appropriate template in tone or content. AI is a useful tool just like a grammar checker even though it doesn't get it right all the time.

I certainly share some of your opinions and anxieties over AI language models - as technically impressive as they are, they are deeply flawed. If you spend any time using Chat GPT, for example, you can easily talk it out of an answer that it confidently gave you, after which it will apologise and give a completely different, equally confident-sounding answer. It's easy to view Chat GPT as an "unreliable narrator" - someone who should not be trusted and therefore not listened to. But take a step back and remember that Chat GPT is not a person.
AI language models might be better viewed as the logical evolution of search engines. Ten years ago we saw the introduction of Google, Alexa, Siri etc as 'search assistants' which were really just basic voice interfaces for accessing the search results you previously had to type to get. You couldn't always trust those to get you the results you wanted, as anyone who has tried asking Google to "play Moana from Disney Plus on the back room TV" will know ("Okay, playing Madonna 'Dress You Up' on the bedroom TV"). True, AI language models are capable of a lot more than these search assistants, but when used to return a simple answer to a question from internet resources, which is what most people are using them for, they are really just an evolution of those.
One of the conditions already existing on ELL is that posters must have done at least some cursory research into their answer. A cursory Google search would satisfy that rule - if an OP said "I found a website that said this..." we'd probably be fine with that, and if said website was wrong then we'd say so and perhaps provide some links to better resources.
Chat GPT and the like are either searching the web and presenting their findings, or producing an answer based on cached internet resources. When challenged, they search again or look to a different resource. Initial results from Chat GPT are not so different from that cursory Google search. Thinking about it rationally (I may have previously said otherwise in answers or comments) I don't have too much of a problem with questions that say "Chat GPT said this..." because that's the OP doing some research.
So - should we publish a warning that Chat GPT cannot be trusted? I don't think that is necessary any more than a warning that some websites cannot be trusted would be necessary. Although a small minority of questions come over as if the OP is trying to prove an incorrect notion they already believe or want to double down on, the vast majority of questions are in the spirit of the site and the OP wants to learn from native English speakers or advanced learners, and the very fact they have brought a question to the table after Chat GPT has given them an answer ought to indicate that they do not trust it 100 per cent. What I definitely won't do is 'argue' with anyone who insists that Chat GPT must be right. Sometimes it just isn't possible to tell a person that someone, or some thing, isn't trustworthy. You just have to point them at the right answer and hope they go with it.
